# Finding a vector that points towards a coordinate

Tags: vectors, spherical-coordinates

How to find a vector $v$ with a magnitude $m$ that starts at $(0, 0, 0)$ (or any other arbitrary coordinate) and points *towards* a coordinate $(x, y, z)$.
For example, let $m$ be 100, and the coordinate be $(200, 0, 0)$. $v$ would then be $(100, 0, 0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may first find the vector which points from your initial, call it $C_0$, coordinate in the direction of the desired, call it $C_d$, coordinate by subtracting: $C_d-C_0$. Then you can divide this vector by its magnitude (assuming you haven’t just created the 0-vector) and multiply the result by your desired magnitude $m$.

Answer (score 0):

Define the target point as ${\bf P}$ and call ${\bf O}$ the origin. The vector going from ${\bf O}$ to ${\bf P}$ is

$$
{\bf u} = {\bf P} - {\bf O}
$$

To make it of norm $m$, just define

$$
{\bf v} = m\frac{{\bf u}}{|{\bf u}|} = m\frac{{\bf P} - {\bf O}}{|{\bf P} - {\bf O}|}
$$